# how to change innerHTML of textarea after typing in it?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

The following code works **only** if I don't first type in the textarea box. If i type in it, clicking on the div does nothing. Is there any way to fix this in javascript or whatever? Any help is appreciated.

```
<textarea id = "textarea">change this</textarea>
<div onclick = "change()">click here<div>

<script>
function change()
    {
        document.getElementById( 'textarea' ).innerHTML = 'new text';
    }
</script>
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/69n24agz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change innerHTML to value,

```
<textarea id = "textarea">change this</textarea>
<div onclick = "change()">click here<div>

<script>
    function change()
    {
        document.getElementById( 'textarea' ).value = 'new text';
    }
</script>
```

a textarea has a value that can be altered, the innerHTML here just sets the initial value.

Comment: A `textarea` element does have an `innerHTML` property; it just sets the *initial* value of the element.